# Use IBM IIB mqsichangeproperties to change SOAPRequest WebService URL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Can I use IBM IIB mqsichangeproperties to change SOAPRequest WebService URL. This will help in avoiding a redeployment when the URLs change slightly without any change to the XSDs. Also helps when migrating from test to production

Comment: @Machavity, this question has nothing to do with [ibm-mq].  IIB is the the [ibm-integration-bus] product.

Comment: @Machavity I have been, I also added some other IBM tags and notes on the Meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/the-ibm-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated#370427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not, normally the command can affect SOAPInput SOAPReply nodes and to modify in SOAPRequest I would use mqsiapplybaroverride, verifying exactly as it is called in the URL bar with mqsireadbar. The downside is you have to redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

mqsichangeproperties would help you change the hostname of IntegrationNode. The hostname will change for different environments from test to PROD as you will have different Integration Nodes for each of em.What you will change is the suffix like in the URI

http://hostname:7080/**ProductDetails_v3**

Which you could do by overriding it using a properties file with mqsiapplybaroverride or you can fetch the suffix from a DB store it in some variable & provide it in LocalEnvironment before making the request.

Please refer the link for LocalEnvironment Overrides for SOAPRequest Nodes

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56192_.htm